# Moving circle within an Animate by clicking on the contents pane

Tags: animation, eventhandler, dynamic

I made this:

```
kszamolo[pos_] := Table[{Round[pos[[1]]/d], Round[pos[[2]]/d]}, {d, 1, 4}];

DynamicModule[{lk = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}}, 
  EventHandler[
    Animate[
      Graphics[Disk[lk[[a]], 5], 
        Frame -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {{-50, 50}, {-50, 50}}], 
      {a, 1, 4}, 
      AnimationRunning -> True, 
      AnimationRepetitions -> 1], 
    {"MouseDown" :> (lk = kszamolo[MousePosition["Animate"]])}]]
```

My goal is to create a window in which I can click in, at which time, the circle should take four steps, one-by-one, on the line between the `{0,0}` and `MousePosition`. I think my code has several problems. I'm a beginner, so any help would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}},
 ClickPane[
  Graphics[{Orange, Dynamic@Disk[pt]}, PlotRange -> 5, Frame -> True],
  With[{w = MousePosition["Graphics"] - pt}, 
    Do[pt += w/4.; Pause[.1]; FinishDynamic[]; Print[pt], {4}]] &]
]
```

At the end you can use `Eventhandler` but for testing `ClickPane` is quite handy here. Feel free to ask if anything is not clear.